# Set cookie in request and response

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, ionic3, express-session

I am facing an issue of cookies.

when I hit the /products request from the browser, the node-express server responds with a cookie and for further requests the same cookie is used to maintain the session.

When I hit the same request /products from ionic app, the server is returning the cookie parameter (developer tool) but for further request the ionic app does not set the cookie in request.
How can I set the cookie in ionic app?

Comment: Perhaps, you have to login from the ionic app to set a cookie and retrieve it. Remember, browser and ionic app are two different clients and you're supposed to login separately from both the apps in case you've session based authentication or use the same access_token if the app is based on OAuth.

Comment: @NishantGhodke The actual issue is that I am hitting the request only from the ionic app but the in response from server cookie is not set. Similarly, if I hit the same request either from browser or postman then server is responding the cookies. So how can I set and get the cookies in ionic app.

Answer (score 1):

The actual issue was due to CORS. I have added following code on server side and everything worked fine for me.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8100");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  next();
});
```

Now the server return the cookie and this cookie is stored and further automatically used in upcomming requests.

Answer (score 0):

Store that cookie in localstorage of the ionic application. Read that cookie from localstorage before sending every request, and then attach your http request.

Comment: How to get the cookies in ionic from the response?

Comment: Also if I set cookie in headers from the app then this error is displayed on console 'Refused to set unsafe header "cookie"'